# Good way to format data in a large DataTable

Tags: vb.net, formatting, datatable

I have a large data.DataTable and some formatting rules to apply.  I'm sure this is not a unique problem.

For example, the LASTNAME column has a value of "Jones" but my formatting rule requires it be 10 characters padded with spaces on the right and uppercase only.  Like: "JONES     "

My initial thought is to loop through each row and generate a string.  But, I wonder if I could accomplish this more efficiently with a DataView, LINQ or something else.

Can someone point me in a direction?

Comment: Why dont you do it in the SQL that returns the dataset for you?

Comment: The data doesn't always come from a DMBS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends how you display the results. I would say if you display it in a grid, the easiest would be to do a quick loop, no real performance harm there in a datatable.

If you display the records individually you can create an extension method for your string, and simply call it like this for example. LastName.Padded()

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static string Padded(this string s)
   {
       return s.ToUpper().PadRight(10);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That seems straight-forward and reasonable.  I guess I mostly wanted to make sure there was something I was overlooking.